# Getting an Error in JSP page as well as controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am getting an error in my JSP page when I am trying to run my spring web page.
Errors are:

1. An exception occurred processing [jsp/welcome.jsp] at line [42]
2. org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [jsp/welcome.jsp] at line [42]
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'question' available as request attribute
4. One different error is when I am login to my web app it still shows `http://localhost:8080/caseStudyNew/login` instead of `http://localhost:8080/caseStudyNew/welcome` or `http://localhost:8080/caseStudyNew/login/welcome`

below is code of JSP page and controller

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859 1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: cursive;
        }

        body {
            background-color: rgb(70, 187, 233);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <tr>
        <td>Welcome ${firstname}</td>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></td>
    </tr>

    <h1 class="heading">Welcome</h1>
    <h2 class="heading">Problem shared is a problem solved!</h2>

    <form:form id="quesForm" modelAttribute="question" formactiom="question" method="post">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="ques">Enter Your Question</form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="ques" name="ques" id="ques" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="ques_desc">Add the Description</form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="ques_desc" name="ques_desc" id="ques_desc" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:button id="ques_submit" name="submit">Ask!</form:button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form:form>

</html>
```

Controller Code:

```
package jbr.springmvc.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import jbr.springmvc.model.Question;
import jbr.springmvc.service.UserService;


@Controller
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        mav.addObject("question", new Question());

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                @ModelAttribute("question") Question question) {

        userService.question(question);

        return new ModelAndView("Hey your", "question", question.getQues());
    }

}
```

Model Code

```
package jbr.springmvc.model;

public class Question {
    private int quesid;

    private String ques;
    private String ques_desc;


    public int getQuesid() {
        return quesid;
    }
    public void setQuesid(int quesid) {
        this.quesid = quesid;
    }

    public String getQues() {
        return ques;
    }
    public void setQues(String ques) {
        this.ques = ques;
    }
    public String getQues_desc() {
        return ques_desc;
    }
    public void setQues_desc(String ques_desc) {
        this.ques_desc = ques_desc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating no-arg constructor for the Question class.
public Question(){
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).